# Ask for a password before restoring a minimized window

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I'm searching how to ask for a password before a minimized window is restored.

Actually, when I restore the window, the main form is visible before the password dialog is shown. (I use the "Resize" event to call my password dialog on the form restore.)

But I need to show the password dialog *before* the main form is visible (because it contains sensitive data that can't be visible to unauthorized people)

Any idea to made the main form invisible until the passord is validated.

thanks

Comment: On any vista or 7 machine, it's very easy to get around your security system. Just mouse over the window in the task bar. I'd suggest finding a different way. (Perhaps you could hide the contents of the form until the password is entered correctly?)

Comment: I agree with that but as the thumbnail is very small, the content is not readable, so it's not a problem for me.

Comment: What about the `Ctrl+Win+Tab` thing. it has very large previews.

Comment: I forgot this one, but it's not a problem, I'll replace the thumbnail with the windowsAPIcodePack (that allow to customizer the win+tab thumbnails & the taskbar preview)

Comment: windowsAPICodePack is definitly not a solution (due to company guideline, if I want to use an external apckage it has to be validated by our standart dept (and it take month). so if anybody has another solution. hidding controls/mdi or adding a panel don't work. It seem that windows 7 take a screenshot before resing the form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All proposed solution didn't works:
It seem that Win7 take a screenshot of your application BEFORE the resize event occurs, so the main form is still visible in the thumbnail even if you add a panel (or if you try to hide some controls).

The solution I found : catch click on the minimize button and display a panel over the main form -> this occurs just before the resize event and windows 7 take this picture as thumbnail.

and a code sample:

```
    private const int WM_SYSCOMMAND = 0x0112; 
    private const int SC_MINIMIZE = 0xf020;
    protected override void WndProc(ref Message m) 
    { 
        if (m.Msg == WM_SYSCOMMAND) 
        { 
            if (m.WParam.ToInt32() == SC_MINIMIZE) 
            { 
                m.Result = IntPtr.Zero; 
                panel1.Height = this.Height; // cover the whole form
                panel1.Width = this.Width;
                panel1.Visible = true; // make it visible
            }
        } 
        base.WndProc(ref m); 
    }
```

Answer (score 5):

You could handle the [`Resize`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.resize.aspx) event of the form and make all controls invisible when being *minimized*.

Then, in turn, hande the `Resize` event for the form being restored, ask for the password and make all controls visible again.

E.g.:

```
private void MyForm_Resize(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if ( WindowState == FormWindowState.Minimized )
    {
        // Hide controls.
    }
    else if ( WindowState == FormWindowState.Normal )
    {
        // Ask for password, then show controls.
    }
}
```

To simplify the showing/hiding of the controls, simply use a `Panel` control as the only direct child of the form, place all controls inside this panel and make this one visible/invisble:

[image]

*(The green one in the image symbolizes the `Panel` control)*

Comment: I can't use this because my main form is too complex. It contains a header (with sensitive data) and a MDI container with multiple child form.

Comment: Your mainform can then hide its MDI children if it an MDI container. Then after the login, restore the window positions.

Answer (score 4):

This sounds like a workaround. Why not create an overlay panel or work with the visibility of the contents of the window? Then you have full control over what people can see.

As said before, the app preview, (and the alt+tab, windows+tab etc) will also show the contents.

Comment: with the windowsAPIcodePack you can replce the generated thumbnai.

Comment: Then it still is a workaround. You just 'assume' there is no other way possible to see the window.  (It is no problem however if you accept this way or security is enough. In your example; visibility for people when clicking the app).

Comment: After more test and reflexion, it's the most sure solution

Comment: @Webmixer I don't mind whether you find my answer the best solution. However we do prefer not to change the accepted flag that much.

Answer (score 1):

You could set the `Visible`-Property of the form to `false` until the password is entered so the form isn't really visible, but I agree with Aphelion, that an overlay may be the better choice...

Comment: This solution works. and if I set the form visible to false and the password dialog visible to true when the user minimize the main form, windows 7 only show the password request as preview. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

A safer / more reliable approach would be to simply black out the contents of your application when you minimize.

Give the overlay you create a textbox to enter the password, and you are golden.